# MKMapView crashing randomly - VKMapCameraController

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

We are getting a large number of crashes in our iOS app which is related to maps. Logs from Fabric are not helpful. We were unable to reproduce it and not able to figure out valid reasoning around it.

```
                                  0x20f34b530 objc_msgSend + 16
1  VectorKit                      0x2204a8e3c __97-[VKMapCameraController panWithOffset:relativeToScreenPoint:animated:duration:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.195 + 32
2  VectorKit                      0x2203c1574 -[VKAnimation stopAnimation:] + 124
3  VectorKit                      0x2203c5020 -[VKTimedAnimation stopAnimation:] + 48
4  VectorKit                      0x2203e7bc0 md::AnimationManager::stopAllAnimations() + 132
5  VectorKit                      0x22065e7d8 md::MapEngine::~MapEngine() + 148
6  VectorKit                      0x22065e73c md::MapEngine::~MapEngine() + 12
7  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20f3327cc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20f3426b8 objc_destructInstance + 68
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20f342720 object_dispose + 16
10 QuartzCore                     0x2145df728 -[CALayer dealloc] + 128
11 VectorKit                      0x2203ccacc -[VKMapView dealloc] + 940
12 QuartzCore                     0x21457c340 CA::Transaction::commit() + 1208
13 QuartzCore                     0x21457ccf8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2100e989c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2100e45c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2100e4b40 __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
17 CoreFoundation                 0x2100e4354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
18 GraphicsServices               0x2122e479c GSEventRunModal + 104
19 UIKitCore                      0x23c550b68 UIApplicationMain + 212
20 trains                         0x102ed9940 main (NotificationManager.swift:20)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x20fbaa8e0 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In my situation this occurs when the zoom animation is happening and I move away from this mapview.

I avoid this crash by disabling the animation:

```
self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
self.mapView.setCenter(annotation.coordinate, animated: false)
```